# // comments in doxygen

Tags: c#, comments, doxygen

I have a c# project that I need to document with doxygen. It picks up the comments autogenerated by visual studio's `///` but unfortunately it does not pick up on the normal `//` comments. Is there a config setting that I am missing? Or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`///` is referred to as [XML Documentation Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx). This is how Doxygen and other documentation-generating software locate areas of the code you **want** to be used as documentation.

To elaborate, if you have comments like `// This is hacky, but I'll return to it later` in your code you should change them to an XML comment section on the method, property, or object in question.

Answer (score 2):

To me this is not a bug but a feature. There are comments that I do want to leave in the code and not extract and show everyone. The distinction between the /// and the // allows me to do this.