# Setting to include // in Doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have a large code base that I'd like to make a first pass documentation with Doxygen but it doesn't have the required /// comment format -- they're all //. Is there a setting to include all comments? I've used Doxygen in the past and understand why you'd want both formats, so please no educations on the difference :). The question was asked before here - [// comments in doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176893/comments-in-doxygen) - but not answered.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution. There is a difference between `//` and `///` (or `//!` and others), so there is no reason for that feature to even exist. For me, it feels the same as having a compiler option, that would e.g. look for variable definitions even in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things you can do:

First, let Doxygen generate what documentation it can automatically, from just the code structure, using either `EXTRACT_ALL = TRUE` or both `HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES = FALSE` and `HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS = FALSE`.

Then, Doxygen supports a preprocessor.  Perhaps you can write a filter than automatically changes `/*` to `/**` and `//` to `///`?  Depending on your code, a dumb filter might or might not break things (do those combinations appear in string literals, for example?)

Finally, the Doxygen code isn't hard to hack.  You should be able to cause `//` and `/*` to be recognized as documentation without much difficulty.